# Create and run a new progress every click on addTabItem and Start Button

Tags: c#, wpf, task, progress-bar

I'm trying to create and start a new progressBar every click action on button start that exist in the new TabItem ( after clicking on the "+") , so the goal is to run multiple progressBar in the same time , these progressBar will be created on each new Tab Item , and will run when clicking on Start Button of ( each tab ) , so each tab item will have a Button and a progressBar .

How can I do this?

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    private List<TabItem> _tabItems;
    private TabItem _tabAdd;
    ProgressBar pr;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        try
        {
            

            InitializeComponent();

            // initialize tabItem array
            _tabItems = new List<TabItem>();

            // add a tabItem with + in header 
            _tabAdd = new TabItem();
            _tabAdd.Header = "+";
            // tabAdd.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(tabAdd_MouseLeftButtonUp);

            _tabItems.Add(_tabAdd);

            // add first tab
            this.AddTabItem();

            // bind tab control
            tabDynamic.DataContext = _tabItems;

            tabDynamic.SelectedIndex = 0;

      
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private TabItem AddTabItem()
    {
        int count = _tabItems.Count;
        pr = new ProgressBar();
        pr.Width = 150;
        pr.Height = 30;
        // create new tab item
        TabItem tab = new TabItem();

        tab.Header = string.Format("Tab {0}", count);
        tab.Name = string.Format("tab{0}", count);
        tab.HeaderTemplate = tabDynamic.FindResource("TabHeader") as DataTemplate;

        tab.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(tab_MouseDoubleClick);

        // add controls to tab item, this case I added just a textbox
        StackPanel st = new StackPanel();
        st.Width = 350;
        st.Height = 350;
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Width = 150;
        btn.Height = 30;
        st.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        st.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        btn.Name = "txt";
        btn.Content = "Start";
        btn.Click += Btn_Click;
        Border b = new Border();
        b.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        b.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10);
        st.Children.Add(btn);
        st.Children.Add(b);
        st.Children.Add(pr);
        st.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        tab.Content = st;

        // insert tab item right before the last (+) tab item
        _tabItems.Insert(count - 1, tab);

        return tab;
    }

    private async void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(async () => {
                var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
                {
                    pr.Value = percent;
                });

                pr.Value = 1;

                int value = 90000;
                await Task.Run(() => DoSomeWork(value, progress));
            }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);


        });
    }
    public async Task DoSomeWork(int iterations, IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => {
                s *= s * i;
                progress.Report(i * 100 / iterations);
            });
        };
    }
private void tabAdd_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // clear tab control binding
        tabDynamic.DataContext = null;

        TabItem tab = this.AddTabItem();

        // bind tab control
        tabDynamic.DataContext = _tabItems;

        // select newly added tab item
        tabDynamic.SelectedItem = tab;
    }

    private void tab_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem tab = sender as TabItem;

        TabProperty dlg = new TabProperty();

        // get existing header text
        dlg.txtTitle.Text = tab.Header.ToString();

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            // change header text
            tab.Header = dlg.txtTitle.Text.Trim();
        }
    }

    private void tabDynamic_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem tab = tabDynamic.SelectedItem as TabItem;
        if (tab == null) return;

        if (tab.Equals(_tabAdd))
        {
            // clear tab control binding
            tabDynamic.DataContext = null;

            TabItem newTab = this.AddTabItem();

            // bind tab control
            tabDynamic.DataContext = _tabItems;

            // select newly added tab item
            tabDynamic.SelectedItem = newTab;
        }
        else
        {
            // your code here...
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="tabDynamic" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="tabDynamic_SelectionChanged">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                <DockPanel>
                    <Button Name="btnDelete" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Header}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="MaxLines" Value="5000"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

**TabProperty.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60px"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Label Content="Tab Title:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" />
    <TextBox Name="txtTitle" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="OK" Name="btnOK" IsDefault="True" Height="23" Click="btnOK_Click"></Button>
        <Button Content="Cancel" Name="btnCancel" IsCancel="True" Height="23"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**TabProperty.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class TabProperty : Window
    {
        public TabProperty()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `How can I do this?` - what have you tried?

Comment: @StephenCleary , and what I wrote isn't considered an attempt?

Comment: I've tried creating a new `ProgressBar` every call of `AddTabItem`